# Programatically instrument an app for use with Quamotion WebDriver

Tags: c#, webdriver, instrumentation

I'm automating an iOS app using `Quamotion WebDriver`. This app uses a couple of custom controls which don't work very well with Apple's UI Automation (i.e. they get reported as `XCUIElementOther*` with very little information about what they are/which text they display). Hence, I want to use App Automation/instrumentation to automate my app.

I'm able to successfully launch the Spy for this app in App Automation mode.

I now want to automatically instrument this app. Can I use the Quamotion.Malaga NuGet package to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to instrument the application yourself. The Quamotion WebDriver does the check and instruments the application if needed.

The workflow is like this:

1. You add your application to the Quamotion app repository (local).
2. You create a new session, specifying the App ID and version of your application.

You can use this code:

```cs
// Add your application to the app repository
Application application = WebDriverExtensions.AddApplication(yourAppPath);

// Start an application session
AppCapabilities appCapabilities = new AppCapabilities(
         deviceId: yourDeviceId
         appId: application.AppId,
         appVersion: application.Version,
         clearApplicationSettings: false
); 
appCapabilities.ReuseSession(true);
AppDriver = new AppDriver(appCapabilities);
```